# ODBC Driver Manager The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: odbc, powerbuilder

I have created an ODBC connection in PB10 Data Source and once I attempt to connect, below stop sign error occurs. Any idea on how to resolve this kind of connection error?

Error : ODBC Driver Manager The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Also, you could try to create the 32-bit ODBC in the 64-bit Operating System.

Here's the exe you need to execute to create 32-bit ODBC in a 64-bit Operating System.
c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: This was the answer for me. Here's a link that has more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Turns out there are 2 versions of odbcad32.exe, one that will allow you to create a working DSN to a 64-bit system, and one that will allow you to create one, and everything will be fine until you actually use it, then it will give you an architecture mismatch error. Guess which one is the default!

Answer (score 3):

Use odbcad32.exe under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ to configure the DSN.

Comment: Care to explain your solution or show some references?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are on 64-bit system and that the DSN you try to connect to uses a 64-bit odbc driver. PowerBuilder applications are 32-bit and can only use 32-bit odbc drivers.

Comment: yes i'm using a 64-bit OS.  The PB application has a MS ACCESS DataBase that's why I'm trying to connect through ODBC. If that would be the case, I should migrate the MS ACCESS to MS SQL. Thanks.